# Codeblocks printf bug with release mode

Tags: c, codeblocks

UPDATE 25/7/23:

I would like to thank the commenters for helping me to try and resolve this issue. I am not sure where the issue was with the bug that I was facing but as a last resort uninstalling and reinstalling code::blocks seemed to resolve this inconvenient bug(I hope). In addition, a couple of things that future people with similar issues can try is to disable their antivirus software first to localise the issue before trying to compile anything as it may be detected as a virus and hence unable to compile, which unfortunately did not work for me but it may for you. I am still dumbfounded by this bug, however.

I need a little bit of help with this bug that im facing. I can't print a string that is more than 7 characters and less than 14 characters in release mode, but it works fine in debug mode.

Issue 1:

For instance, if i wanted to print "Hello World", i can't as it doesn't meet the string requirement issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
   printf("Hello World \n");
}
```

Output:

```
Process returned 32766 (0x7FFE)   execution time : 1.581 s
Press any key to continue.
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{

   printf("Hello Worldssss \n");

}
```

Output:

```
Hello Worldssss

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.020 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Issue 2:

And also i cant seem to print float values with precision if i don't supply the printf statement with enough characters and it also underlines %.2f in red for some reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{

   float a = 2.34323;

   printf("%.2f", a);

}
```

Output:

```
Process returned 32766 (0x7FFE)   execution time : 1.585 s
Press any key to continue.
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{

   float a = 2.34323;

   printf("This is a test: %.2f", a);

}
```

Output:

```
This is a test: 2.34
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.625 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I am clueless, i don't know what on earth is going on, I'm sure as heck it worked a few months ago, i have never touched the installation files/ properties and whatnot and this issue is driving me nuts. I understand that sometimes antivirus software can mess with codeblocks but it doesn't seem to be the case either. Has anyone face this issue before?

Additional info: Im currently running Windows 10 with code::blocks version 20.03

Comment: Are you including `stdio.h`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja , yes i did!

Comment: We need to narrow down the location of the issue. What happens when you run the "non-working" executables outside of Code::blocks? Open a command prompt, navigate to the executable's directory, and run it.

Comment: It makes no sense to remove the single include line leaving us to guess if you did or did not include it and then leave extra whitespace in the code you have shown.

Comment: We need to widen the visible code, please provide a [mre] for each shown case. Because if you left out the necessary includes you might also have left out the offending lines.

Comment: @thebusybee same issue if i were to run it from terminal, it works fine in vscode however. Ill try a clean install of codeblocks again to see if it fixes it.

Comment: So you claim that the "short" version of "hello world" prints nothing in the terminal? Then it is not an issue of the IDE, but of the compiler/library/linker. However, it might have been installed with the IDE. -- Please [edit] your question and provide your OS and version of Code::blocks.

Comment: @thebusybee it may cause the environment to report non-zero exit status, prior to C99

Comment: @M.M So you think the OP uses a compiler older than 20 years? =-O

Comment: @CherryDT hmm it works exactly the same with or without the return statement but i included it nonetheless

Comment: That code looks obviously correct, so the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: You might want to emphasize the common result on the non-working versions: The IDE reports a returned value of 32766. A quick web research revealed no relevant hits, though, with the exception of the already mentioned antivirus issue. Unfortunately, the documentation of Code::blocks says nothing to this. -- What happens if you single-step by the debugger?

Comment: Are you doing the compilation through the IDE or in the terminal? Perhaps the IDE includes non-standard stdio-headers for debugging.

Comment: Can you post the "build log" of the compilation?

Comment: It looks like you are using windows, where a line-ending should be `\r\n`. Can you try to add that to all of your lines? stdio-implementations typically flush at line-endings. Or add an explicit `fflush(stdout);`. (This is not a solution attempt, it is an attempt to get more info)

Comment: @julaine -- Windows represents line-endings with `\r\n`, but you don't need to use this in print statements; `\n` specifically should flush line-buffered streams. The `\r\n` will show up in source code files as line-endings, but C compilers must convert these to `\n` characters during the translation phase. This _can_ be an issue, e.g., when reading a file which was created in a Windows environment from a program running in a Linux environment. Explicitly calling `fflush` is good advice when trying to troubleshoot IO mishaps since the flushing behavior of `\n` is implementation-defined.

Comment: @solace, concerning `float a = 2.34323; printf("%.2f", a);`.  Some  compilers do not link in the FP math library with there is no FP math going on - even though `printf()` needs it.  Try adding some real FP math before printing.

Comment: @adabsurdum I have looked into this because it conflicted my understanding of C. You are correct. Hosted implementations of C require printf to convert `\n`. I did find this document describing that it is different for freestanding implementations: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka003309/latest/

Comment: Can you give us the exact command you (or the IDE) use for compilation? Posting code is normally enough to make a reproducible example but in this case it is not.

Comment: Glad you resolved it but I am a bit sad because I hoped this would be one of those questions that lead to the depths of historically grown programming language implementations or obscure windows features.